# error while trying to remove java

Tags: java, uninstall

I am using linux 16.10 i installed java using this commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt update
sudo apt install oracle-java8-installer
sudo apt install oracle-java9-installer
```

(I've seen later that i could install java 9)

```
sudo apt install oracle-java8-set-default
```

Now I need to remove java because it is too recent and it probably doesn't have a library that is needed by another program. (op-jre 1.5.0-22)

I located java with:

```
$ whereis java
/usr/bin/java /usr/share/java
```

Now with terminal I went in `/usr/share` and typed `rm -r java`.
I removed java but now I see many other folders in `/usr/share/` which contains the word `java` and I suppose I have to delete them too to completely delete java, but when I type `rm -r javaws` 
I get this output:

```
rm -r javaws
rm: cannot remove 'javaws': No such file or directory
```

but I see it!

How do I remove Java completely?

Comment: "Now with terminal I went in /usr/share and typed rm -r java" **DON'T DO THIS!** We have package managers to handle the nitty-gritty of removing all the package's various files for you. To remove a package, just type `sudo apt remove PACKAGE` or `sudo apt purge PACKAGE` where PACKAGE is the package's name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove packages on Ubuntu, use `sudo apt remove`:

```
sudo apt remove oracle-java8-installer
sudo apt remove oracle-java9-installer
sudo apt remove oracle-java8-set-default
```

These are the same commands that you used to install these packages except replacing the word "install" with "remove".

Once you do that, you can install Java with:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre
```

This OpenJDK version is open-source and is the preferred option.

Oh and, please never try to remove any program with `rm` ever again.